# Is it possible to mount one H.D.D. via USB Hub on two PCs?

Tags: linux, usb, mount

Having a HDD Drive on a USB hub with two partitions. Can I mount first partition to Computer A and second partition to Computer B without trouble?

Or even better, would it be possible to mount one partition to both computers?

thanks.

Comment: Once the partition is mounted on a computer, you can share it to the other computer. The method depends of your distro.

Comment: I am looking for a USB share rather than a network/ethernet share. but thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted on [unix & linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107833/22222).

Comment: If need 1 partition use ocfs2, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_disk_file_system first scheme approach for any operating systems and will work without error.